# Array containing the 24 sequence of 24 hours before 24 hour time

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have found a way to find the current 24 hour time of the user through

```
let date = Date()
let calendar = Calendar.current
let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: date) --> e.g.(15)
```

I am wanting to create an array of a sequence of 24 hours before that time. An example of this is below-

```
15
14
...
2
1
24
23 
... and so on
```

I have been able 
to create the list to 1 but instead of going to 0, I have not been able to create a formula that will go to 24.

I currently have -

```
for i in 0...24 {
            var previousHours = 0

            if i >= hour{
              previousHours = hour - 24 + i

            } else {
                 previousHours = hour - i

            }

            hoursArray.append(previousHours)
}
```

Which for hour 20, this list is formed-

```
21,20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,18,19,20,21
```

Instead of

> hour - 24 + I

What formula would produce the correct results? Is there an easier way to have the same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
for i in 1...24 {
    hoursArray.append(i)
}

let myHour = 20 //like your example 

let hoursAfter = hoursArray.filter { $0 > myHour }
let hoursBefore = hoursArray.filter { $0 < myHour }

let cycle = hoursAfter + hoursBefore
```

Here you have hours from 21 - 24 and then from 1 - 19

or if you wnat another way around, make

```
cycle.reversed()
```

Comment: I don't believe this will work when the clock changes.

Comment: why? if clock changes and there is another hour what will change? still lower or higher numbers stays there

Comment: when the clock changes the hours will either go `...12, 1, 1, 2, 3...` or `...12, 1, 3, 4...`

Comment: how? try to run it in playground, everything is right

Comment: that’s how the clocks work. But the code in this answer will not do that... and should do that.

Comment: oh my god you are talking abut 12h clock? that is not a problem at all just change for loop value

Comment: No, I'm not talking about 12 hour clock, I'm talking about how the Gregorian calendar works. When the clocks go back it goes ...12am, 1am, 1am, 2am, 3am... and when the clocks go forwards it goes ...12am, 1am, 3am, 4am... In order to code anything involving time it is always best to use `NSCalendar` to do the calculations for you :)

Comment: Not a problem :) The other answer given also has the same flaw :) but wasn't there when I first commented. Sorry :D

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like something like this?

```
var hrs = [Int]()
var start = 15
while hrs.count < 24 {
    if start < 24 {
        hrs.append(start)
        start += 1
    } else {
        start = 1
    }
}
hrs.reverse()
```

Use calendar to calculate as mentioned by the above comment, this one goes from 0-23:

```
var hrs = [Int]()
let date = Date()
let calendar = Calendar.current
let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: date)
var dayComp = DateComponents()
dayComp.calendar = calendar
dayComp.hour = 0
while hrs.count < 24 {
    let next = calendar.date(byAdding: dayComp, to: date)
    hrs.append(calendar.component(.hour, from: next!))
    dayComp.hour! -= 1
}
```

Output:

> 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19

Answer (score 0):

A small change in your formula from

```
hour - 24 + i
```

to

```
hour - i + 24
```

may solve the problem and will provide output you requires.